# incrementing the x position of an image and then decrement it back is not working in java

Tags: java, image, increment, decrement

im trying to make a 8 puzzle game and my problem is that when the value of x1 let say 70 of a particular image's x position is incremented until it reaches to 170 and then it will be decremented until it reaches to 70 again, but this decrementation is not working and the image is not moving to its original position anymore but it does shaking only. why is this happening. in order to clarify all this stuff you can check my code below:

run.java

```
public class run extends Applet implements Runnable{
    public Image im;    
    public int x1=70, y1=70;
    public int x2=170, y2=70;
    public int x3=270, y3=70;
    public int x4=70, y4=170;
    public int x5=170, y5=170;
    public int x6=270, y6=170;
    public int x7=70, y7=270;
    public int x8=170, y8=270;
    public int x9=270, y9=270;

    public Image offscreen;
    public Graphics d;
    public BufferedImage container;
    public BufferedImage[] tile = new BufferedImage[10];
    private File loadThis;

     public void combi1(){
         if(x1<170 && x1>=70){
             x1+=1; y2+=1; x5-=1; y4-=1;
             return;       
         }
         if(x1>=70){
             x1-=1; y2-=1; x5+=1; y4+=1;
             return;       
         }

     }


    public void run(){

        try{
            URI imageurl = getClass().getResource("container.png").toURI();
            loadThis = new File(imageurl);
            container = ImageIO.read(loadThis);            
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                if(i>=1){
                    URI tileurl = getClass().getResource("tile" + i +".png").toURI();
                    loadThis = new File(tileurl);
                    tile[i] = ImageIO.read(loadThis);
                }
            }                     
            }catch (IOException e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        while(true){                  

            combi1();

            repaint();           

        try{
            Thread.sleep(2);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

    }
}
```

AIprojects.java

```
public class AIprojects extends run{
    public void init(){
        setSize(450,450); 

        Thread th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
        offscreen = createImage(450,450);
        d = offscreen.getGraphics();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        d.setColor(Color.black);        
        d.fillRect(0, 0, 450, 450);
        d.drawImage(container, 52, 52,340,340, this);
        d.drawImage(tile[9], x9, y9, this);
        d.drawImage(tile[1], x1, y1, this);
        d.drawImage(tile[2], x2, y2, this);
        d.drawImage(tile[3], x3, y3, this);
        d.drawImage(tile[4], x4, y4, this);
        d.drawImage(tile[5], x5, y5, this);
        d.drawImage(tile[6], x6, y6, this);
        d.drawImage(tile[7], x7, y7, this);
        d.drawImage(tile[8], x8, y8, this);

        g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);
    }
    public void update(Graphics g){
        paint(g);
    }
}
```

this code is not the actual code i have right now but i posted it here to make all things clear with regards to my problem. thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given

```
    if(x1<170 && x1>=70){
         x1+=1; y2+=1; x5-=1; y4-=1;
         return;       
     }
     if(x1>=70){
         x1-=1; y2-=1; x5+=1; y4+=1;
         return;       
     }
```

what happens when `x1` hits 170 ? You subtract 1. Next time you come in and since `x1` is 169 you add 1, making it 170. And so on *ad infinitum*.

I think you need a variable `direction`, which is 1 or -1. When you hit 170 *or* 70, reverse the value of `direction`. In all cases use `direction` to change `x1` thus

```
x1 += direction;
```

Comment: I already +1'd for pointing out the problem, so unfortunately I cannot +1 for the solution any more ;)